# Make rspec showing variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a test with rspec where I wrote

```rb
before { visit edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token) }
```

I run the associated tests and here what I get :

```rb
No route matches [GET] "/password_resets/edit"
```

In order to understand why it doesn't work, I want to know what's in the `user.password_reset_token`.

How can I make that variable appear when running the tests ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply this:

```
before do 
    puts user.password_reset_token
    visit edit_password_reset_path(user.password_reset_token) 
end
```